# I want to use spi0 and spi1 at the same time

Tags: spi

I want to use LCD and mcp3208 simultaneously.

spi0(gpio8,9,10,11) is port for LCD and spi1(gpio16,19,20,21) is port for mcp3208.

spi0 channel is always on and spi1 is opened when I want to collect data.

Question:

1) when I checked spidev, there are spidev0.0, 0.1 but spidev1.0,1.1. Should I make spidev1.0 and 1,1? If then, How can I make them??

2) Someone said using PIGPIO. so, I installed pigpio is raspberry pi3. My example code is like below.

```
import pigpio
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

pi = pigpio.pi()

if not pi.connected:
    exit(0)

# pi.spi_open(0, 1000000, 0)   # CE0, 1Mbps, main SPI
# pi.spi_open(0, 1000000, PI_SPI_FLAGS_AUX_SPI(1)) # CE0, 1Mbps, auxiliary SPI

lcd=pi.spi_open(0, 1000000, 0) # CE0, main SPI
pi.spi_read(lcd, 2)

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
subprocess.call('setterm -cursor off', shell=True)
subprocess.call('spincl -ib', shell=True)
# pins connected from the SPI port on the ADC to the RPi
SPICLK  = 11
SPIMISO = 9
SPIMOSI = 10
SPICS   = 8

# set up the SPI interface pins

GPIO.setup(SPIMOSI, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(SPIMISO, GPIO.IN )
GPIO.setup(SPICLK,  GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(SPICS,   GPIO.OUT)

# pin connected to read
sensor_adc0 = 0;
sensor_adc1 = 1;
sensor_adc2 = 2;
sensor_adc3 = 3;
sensor_adc4 = 4;
sensor_adc5 = 5;
sensor_adc6 = 6;
sensor_adc7 = 7;
subprocess.call('clear', shell=True)

def readadc(adcnum, clockpin, mosipin, misopin, cspin):
        mcp = pi.spi_open(0, 1000000, PI_SPI_FLAGS_AUX_SPI(1))
        pi.spi_read(mcp, 1)
        if ((adcnum > 7) or (adcnum < 0)):
                return -1
        GPIO.output(cspin   , True)

        GPIO.output(clockpin, False)  # start clock low
        GPIO.output(cspin   , False)  # bring CS low

        commandout = adcnum
        commandout |= 0x18            # start bit + single-ended bit
        commandout <<= 3              # we only need to send 5 bits here
        for i in range(5):
            if (commandout & 0x80):
                GPIO.output(mosipin, True )
            else:
                GPIO.output(mosipin, False)
            commandout <<= 1
            GPIO.output(clockpin, True )
            GPIO.output(clockpin, False)

        adcout = 0

        # read in one empty bit, one null bit and 12 ADC bits
        for i in range(14):
                GPIO.output(clockpin, True )
                GPIO.output(clockpin, False)
                adcout <<= 1
                if (GPIO.input(misopin)):
                        adcout |= 0x1

        GPIO.output(cspin, True)

        adcout >>= 1 # first bit is 'null' so drop it
        pi.spi_close(mcp)
        return adcout

if __name__ == '__main__':
        sensor0 = readadc(sensor_adc0, SPICLK, SPIMOSI, SPIMISO, SPICS)
        print sensor0
```

It didn't work.

How can I fix it??

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The Pi only has kernel drivers for `SPI0` with support for 2 channels. In fact you can use more with your own CE code, and/or hardware. There is no driver for `SPI1` and it impractical to write one. There is plenty of code which uses `SPI1`, and supports additional channels. I don't see why the 2 `SPI0` channels wouldn't work for your 2 devices, but there is non-kernel code to use `SPI1` (I have never had the need).

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. SPI is a bus system.  Only one SPI device can be using the bus at any one instant (the one which has asserted slave select).  What is the output of `ls /dev/spi*`?

Comment: `How can I fix it??`, the best way to fix it is to rewrite your code because it is such a mess. But before you rewrite it, take time to understand how SPI works and read the API document such as pigpio, for how to use [spi_open](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#spi_open) in particular. SPI0 supports two channels by controlling `CE0` and `CE1` while sharing the rest of the signals (MOSI/MISO/CLK) in a time-division manner, but it can't be used `at the same time`.

Answer (score 1):

just add this to /boot/config.txt and reboot

dtoverlay=spi1-3cs

it should enable auxiliary SPI with SPI1 CE2 (GPIO16) for channel select

see also /boot/overlays/README

https://pinout.xyz/pinout/spi

http://librpip.frasersdev.net/peripheral-config/spi1-aux/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the tips.

In my case, just add this to /boot/config.txt and reboot

dtoverlay=spi1-3cs

I changed too in the MFRC522 library the following parameter: /dev/spidev0.0 to /dev/spidev1.0

In the pins were like this:

- SDA/CE2: 36
- MISO: 35
- MOSI: 38
- SCKL: 40
- RESET: 13

Comment: How do you change a parameter in a library? Do you compile it?

Comment: I used this library for the MFRC522 reader (https://github.com/YongxinLIAO/SmartFactoryRFID/blob/master/MFRC522.py). On line 10 (NRSTPD = 22) I changed pin 22 to 13 (MFRC 522 reset pin).